# tikz: table with mathmode and drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, beamer

I made the following table

[image]

in `LaTex` with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ph]
\protect\caption{Genotype-by-Environment Means}
\centering{}%
\begin{tabular}{l|cccccc|c}
\hline 
 & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{Environment} & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-7} 
Genotype & $1$ & $2$ & $\ldots$ & $j$ & $\ldots$ & $e$ & Mean\tabularnewline
\hline 
$1$ & $\overline{Y}_{11.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{12.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{1j.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{1e.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{1..}$\tabularnewline
$2$ & $\overline{Y}_{21.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{22.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{2j.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{2e.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{2..}$\tabularnewline
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$\tabularnewline
$i$ & $\overline{Y}_{i1.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{i2.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{ij.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{ie.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{i..}$\tabularnewline
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$\tabularnewline
$g$ & $\overline{Y}_{g1.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{g2.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{gj.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{ge.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{g..}$\tabularnewline
\hline 
Mean & $\overline{Y}_{.1.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{.2.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{.j.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{.e.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{...}$\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Now I want to make some drawing on this table as below:

[image]

I used `tikz` for this and the code is:

```
\documentclass{article} % article standalone 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset{ 
table/.style={
  matrix of math nodes,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={rectangle,draw=black,text width=3.3em,align=center},
  text depth=0.25ex,
  text height=2ex,
  nodes in empty cells
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [table] {
    %& K=3 & K=4 & K=5 & K=6 & K=7 & K=8 & K=9 & K=10 & K=11 & K=12\\
    \hline
 1  &  \overline{Y}_{11.}  &  \overline{Y}_{12.}  &  \ldots  &  \overline{Y}_{1j.}  &  \ldots  &  \overline{Y}_{1e.}  &  \overline{Y}_{1..} \\
 2  &  \overline{Y}_{21.}  &  \overline{Y}_{22.}  &  \ldots  &  \overline{Y}_{2j.}  &  \ldots  &  \overline{Y}_{2e.}  &  \overline{Y}_{2..} \\
 \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \ddots  &  \vdots  &  \ddots  &  \vdots  &  \vdots \\
 i  &  \overline{Y}_{i1.}  &  \overline{Y}_{i2.}  &  \ldots  &  \overline{Y}_{ij.}  &  \ldots  &  \overline{Y}_{ie.}  &  \overline{Y}_{i..} \\
 \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \ddots  &  \vdots  &  \ddots  &  \vdots  &  \vdots \\
 g  &  \overline{Y}_{g1.}  &  \overline{Y}_{g2.}  &  \ldots  &  \overline{Y}_{gj.}  &  \ldots  &  \overline{Y}_{ge.}  &  \overline{Y}_{g..} \\
\textrm{Mean} &  \overline{Y}_{.1.}  &  \overline{Y}_{.2.}  &  \ldots  &  \overline{Y}_{.j.}  &  \ldots  &  \overline{Y}_{.e.}  &  \overline{Y}_{...} \\
};
\begin{scope}[shorten >= 10pt,shorten <= 10pt]
\draw[red, thick] (m-4-2.west) -- (m-4-8.east);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

---

**Edited**

---

I want to use this table in `beamer`. On first frame the table without marker (red in hand made figure) and one second frame the table with marker (red in hand made figure). So what is the best approach. Thanks

Comment: If you are not going to replace the Y bar variables, this table is in my humble opinion just occupying unnecessary space. It takes two lines to explain your mean notation.

Comment: What do you want to draw? Box the ith row or something else?

Comment: Yes @Jesse: I want to box the i-th row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same idea, but using the [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) library (this allows you to easily place some filling color in the background if desired); I also used [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) to give a more professional look to the table. The overlay is simply achieved using the fact that `\draw` is overlay aware. The code needs three runs to stabilize:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand<>\FramedBox[3][]{%
\draw#4[red!80!black,rounded corners,fill=red!10,#1] 
  ([xshift=-1ex,yshift=3ex]pic cs:#2) 
    rectangle 
  ([xshift=1ex,yshift=-1ex]pic cs:#3);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\FramedBox<2>{starta}{enda}
\FramedBox<3>{startc}{endc}
\FramedBox<4>[draw=cyan,fill=cyan!20]{startb}{endb}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{table}
\caption{Genotype-by-Environment Means}
\centering{}%
\begin{tabular}{lccccccc}
\toprule 
 & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Environment} & 
\tabularnewline
\cmidrule{2-7} 
Genotype & $1$ & $2$ & $\ldots$ & $j$ & $\ldots$ & $e$ & Mean
\tabularnewline
\midrule
$1$ & $\overline{Y}_{11.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{12.}$ & $\ldots$ 
  & \tikzmark{startb}$\overline{Y}_{1j.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{1e.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{1..}$
\tabularnewline
$2$ & $\overline{Y}_{21.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{22.}$ & $\ldots$ 
  & $\overline{Y}_{2j.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{2e.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{2..}$
\tabularnewline
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ 
  & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$
\tabularnewline
$i$ & \tikzmark{starta}$\overline{Y}_{i1.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{i2.}$ 
  & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{ij.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{ie.}$ 
  & $\overline{Y}_{i..}$ \tikzmark{enda} 
\tabularnewline
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ 
  & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$
\tabularnewline
$g$ & $\overline{Y}_{g1.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{g2.}$ & $\ldots$ 
  & $\overline{Y}_{gj.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{ge.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{g..}$
\tabularnewline
\midrule
Mean & $\overline{Y}_{.1.}$ & \tikzmark{startc}$\overline{Y}_{.2.}$\tikzmark{endc} & $\ldots$ 
  & $\overline{Y}_{.j.}$\tikzmark{endb} & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{.e.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{...}$
\tabularnewline
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `\tikzmark` you place two marks for each frame; one where the frame should begin and the other one where it should end. Then you can simply use the command `\FramedBox` inside a `tikzpicture` environment to draw the frames; the syntax for the command is:

```
\FrameBox[<options for the frame>]{<start mark>}{<end mark>}
```

`\FramedBox` is overlay aware, as the example code illustrates.

Comment: (+1): Thanks @Gonzalo for your nice answer. Could you help me too if I have to select also another cell too. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 Which other cell?

Comment: Any other cell. For example, in last row second column element.

Comment: @MYaseen208 Sure. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Simply awesome. Thanks a lot @Gonzalo. Much appreciated. Will award the bounty.

Comment: @MYaseen208 You're welcome! Glad I could help.

Comment: @MYaseen208 I did some modifications to the code that could be of ineterest for you.

Comment: Thanks @Gonzalo for your help. Would you elaborate which modifications you have made? Could you help me to get the same table with boxes in article documentclass. If you think I can ask separate question. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @MYaseen208 I changed the shifts used for the start and end marks in the definition of `\FramedBox`; as they were originally defined they produced the wrong result for vertical boxes. Now they are corrected. Regarding your question with the `article` document class, do you need the filling for the frames or just to draw the borders?

Comment: I think boxes with borders are sufficient. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 this is the `\FramedBox` definition for `article` document class: `\newcommand\FramedBox[3][]{
\draw[red!80!black,rounded corners,#1] 
  ([xshift=-1ex,yshift=3ex]pic cs:#2) 
    rectangle 
  ([xshift=1ex,yshift=-1ex]pic cs:#3);
}` the marks are placed in exactly the same way using `\tikzmar{<mark>}` and this is how you would draw the boxes (without overlay specifications): `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\FramedBox{starta}{enda}
\FramedBox{startc}{endc}
\FramedBox[draw=cyan]{startb}{endb}
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: Thanks again @Gonzalo for your help. Your given code is working but in big document sometimes the boxes are not appearing on correct places. Any solution. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 Try adding the `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}` part inside the `table` environment. If this doesn't solve the problem, please compose a minimal document illustrating the problem and open a fresh new question as a follow-up to this one.

Comment: Hello @Gonzalo, I've asked the follow up question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163614/4821).

Answer (score 5):

You are almost there. Use the 4 corners which can be identified as `north west` `north east` `south east` and `south west` of a cell. Simply select the corresponding cell with care.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article} % article standalone 
\usepackage[papersize={15cm,6cm}]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}

\tikzset{ 
table/.style={
  matrix of math nodes,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={rectangle,draw=black,text width=3.3em,align=center},
  text depth=0.25ex,
  text height=2ex,
  nodes in empty cells
  }
}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [table] {
    %& K=3 & K=4 & K=5 & K=6 & K=7 & K=8 & K=9 & K=10 & K=11 & K=12\\
    \hline
 1  &  \overline{Y}_{11.}  &  \overline{Y}_{12.}  &  \ldots  &  \overline{Y}_{1j.}  &  \ldots  &  \overline{Y}_{1e.}  &  \overline{Y}_{1..} \\
 2  &  \overline{Y}_{21.}  &  \overline{Y}_{22.}  &  \ldots  &  \overline{Y}_{2j.}  &  \ldots  &  \overline{Y}_{2e.}  &  \overline{Y}_{2..} \\
 \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \ddots  &  \vdots  &  \ddots  &  \vdots  &  \vdots \\
 i  &  \overline{Y}_{i1.}  &  \overline{Y}_{i2.}  &  \ldots  &  \overline{Y}_{ij.}  &  \ldots  &  \overline{Y}_{ie.}  &  \overline{Y}_{i..} \\
 \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \vdots  &  \ddots  &  \vdots  &  \ddots  &  \vdots  &  \vdots \\
 g  &  \overline{Y}_{g1.}  &  \overline{Y}_{g2.}  &  \ldots  &  \overline{Y}_{gj.}  &  \ldots  &  \overline{Y}_{ge.}  &  \overline{Y}_{g..} \\
\textrm{Mean} &  \overline{Y}_{.1.}  &  \overline{Y}_{.2.}  &  \ldots  &  \overline{Y}_{.j.}  &  \ldots  &  \overline{Y}_{.e.}  &  \overline{Y}_{...} \\
};
\begin{scope}[shorten >= 10pt,shorten <= 10pt]
\draw[red, thick] (m-4-2.north west) -- (m-4-8.north east) -- (m-4-8.south east) -- (m-4-2.south west) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Edit: The OP's intention was to draw on the first figure. So this is a solution where 4 tikzmarks defined by a command called `tikzmark` are assigned to the ith-row and a line with a style is drawn to box the ith row.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={15cm,10cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,calc}
\tikzset{line/.style ={draw, rounded corners=2pt, line width=1pt}}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
\tikz[remember picture]  \node[inner sep=0,outer sep=0] (#1){};%
}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ph]
\protect\caption{Genotype-by-Environment Means}
\centering{}%
\begin{tabular}{l|cccccc|c}
\hline 
 & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{Environment} & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-7} 
Genotype & $1$ & $2$ & $\ldots$ & $j$ & $\ldots$ & $e$ & Mean\tabularnewline
\hline 
$1$ & $\overline{Y}_{11.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{12.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{1j.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{1e.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{1..}$\tabularnewline
$2$ & $\overline{Y}_{21.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{22.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{2j.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{2e.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{2..}$\tabularnewline
$\vdots$& \tikzmark{a} $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$\tikzmark{b}\tabularnewline
$i$ & \tikzmark{d}$\overline{Y}_{i1.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{i2.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{ij.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{ie.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{i..}\tikzmark{c}$\tabularnewline
$\vdots$&  $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$\tabularnewline
$g$ & $\overline{Y}_{g1.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{g2.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{gj.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{ge.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{g..}$\tabularnewline
\hline 
Mean & $\overline{Y}_{.1.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{.2.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{.j.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{.e.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{...}$\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw [red,line]($(a)+(-2.2ex,0)$)--($(b)+(2.5ex,0)$)--($(c)+(0.9ex,-1ex)$) -- ($(d)+(-0.9ex,-1ex)$)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jesse for your answer. I actually want to get the table exactly like figure 1 with box on i-th row. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208 -- Thank you for your patient. My second attempt is shown/appended for your reference.

Comment: For jesse and @Tobi: I got one issue with your code. For different compilations Red box changes its place.

Comment: @MYaseen208 -- Try using `article` class to compile. To save space, I use small page size area shown on the second line. ie, under normal/usual condition and test.