# tikz: table with mathmode and drawing in article documentclass in LyX

Tags: tikz-pgf, lyx, document-classes

This is a follow up question to my earlier question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160423/4821) (Thanks to @Gonzalo for nice answer). I want to make the same table with boxes in article `documentclass`. My MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand\FramedBox[3][]{%
 \draw[red!80!black,rounded corners,#1]    
   ([xshift=-1ex,yshift=3ex]pic cs:#2)      
      rectangle    
        ([xshift=1ex,yshift=-1ex]pic cs:#3); 
     }


\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{table}[ph]
\protect\caption{Genotype-by-Environment Means}
\centering{}%
\begin{tabular}{l|cccccc|c}
\hline 
 & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{Environment} & \tabularnewline
\cline{2-7} 
Genotype & $1$ & $2$ & $\ldots$ & $j$ & $\ldots$ & $e$ & Mean\tabularnewline
\hline 
$1$ & $\overline{Y}_{11.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{12.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{1j.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{1e.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{1..}$\tabularnewline
$2$ & $\overline{Y}_{21.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{22.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{2j.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{2e.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{2..}$\tabularnewline
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$\tabularnewline
$i$ & $\overline{Y}_{i1.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{i2.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{ij.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{ie.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{i..}$\tabularnewline
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$\tabularnewline
$g$ & $\overline{Y}_{g1.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{g2.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{gj.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{ge.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{g..}$\tabularnewline
\hline 
Mean & $\overline{Y}_{.1.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{.2.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{.j.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{.e.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{...}$\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\Blindtext

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] 
\FramedBox{starta}{enda} 
\FramedBox{startc}{endc} 
\FramedBox[draw=cyan]{startb}{endb} 
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{table}
\caption{Genotype-by-Environment Means}
\centering{}%
\begin{tabular}{lccccccc}
\toprule 
 & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Environment} & 
\tabularnewline
\cmidrule{2-7} 
Genotype & $1$ & $2$ & $\ldots$ & $j$ & $\ldots$ & $e$ & Mean
\tabularnewline
\midrule
$1$ & $\overline{Y}_{11.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{12.}$ & $\ldots$ 
  & \tikzmark{startb}$\overline{Y}_{1j.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{1e.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{1..}$
\tabularnewline
$2$ & $\overline{Y}_{21.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{22.}$ & $\ldots$ 
  & $\overline{Y}_{2j.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{2e.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{2..}$
\tabularnewline
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ 
  & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$
\tabularnewline
$i$ & \tikzmark{starta}$\overline{Y}_{i1.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{i2.}$ 
  & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{ij.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{ie.}$ 
  & $\overline{Y}_{i..}$ \tikzmark{enda} 
\tabularnewline
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ 
  & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$
\tabularnewline
$g$ & $\overline{Y}_{g1.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{g2.}$ & $\ldots$ 
  & $\overline{Y}_{gj.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{ge.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{g..}$
\tabularnewline
\midrule
Mean & $\overline{Y}_{.1.}$ & \tikzmark{startc}$\overline{Y}_{.2.}$\tikzmark{endc} & $\ldots$ 
  & $\overline{Y}_{.j.}$\tikzmark{endb} & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{.e.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{...}$
\tabularnewline
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\blindtext
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

It works fine. But if I export this to `LyX` then I have problems. In `LyX Version 2.1.0beta2` even after multiple compilations, node positions are wrong. See attached figure. [image]

Any idea to do this in `LyX`. Thanks

---

### **Edited**

Using @Gonzalo code, every thing works fine but after exporting to LyX I'm getting the following output with problems with node positions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table floats, the boxes will end in a different page; to prevent this, draw the boxes inside the corresponding `table` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand\FramedBox[3][]{%
  \draw[red!80!black,rounded corners,#1]    
    ([xshift=-1ex,yshift=3ex]pic cs:#2)      
      rectangle    
   ([xshift=1ex,yshift=-1ex]pic cs:#3); 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p]
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] 
\FramedBox{starta}{enda} 
\FramedBox{startc}{endc} 
\FramedBox[draw=cyan]{startb}{endb} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Genotype-by-Environment Means}
\centering{}%
\begin{tabular}{lccccccc}
\toprule 
 & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Environment} & 
\tabularnewline
\cmidrule{2-7} 
Genotype & $1$ & $2$ & $\ldots$ & $j$ & $\ldots$ & $e$ & Mean
\tabularnewline
\midrule
$1$ & $\overline{Y}_{11.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{12.}$ & $\ldots$ 
  & \tikzmark{startb}$\overline{Y}_{1j.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{1e.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{1..}$
\tabularnewline
$2$ & $\overline{Y}_{21.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{22.}$ & $\ldots$ 
  & $\overline{Y}_{2j.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{2e.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{2..}$
\tabularnewline
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ 
  & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$
\tabularnewline
$i$ & \tikzmark{starta}$\overline{Y}_{i1.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{i2.}$ 
  & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{ij.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{ie.}$ 
  & $\overline{Y}_{i..}$ \tikzmark{enda} 
\tabularnewline
$\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ & $\vdots$ & $\ddots$ 
  & $\vdots$ & $\vdots$
\tabularnewline
$g$ & $\overline{Y}_{g1.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{g2.}$ & $\ldots$ 
  & $\overline{Y}_{gj.}$ & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{ge.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{g..}$
\tabularnewline
\midrule
Mean & $\overline{Y}_{.1.}$ & \tikzmark{startc}$\overline{Y}_{.2.}$\tikzmark{endc} & $\ldots$ 
  & $\overline{Y}_{.j.}$\tikzmark{endb} & $\ldots$ & $\overline{Y}_{.e.}$ & $\overline{Y}_{...}$
\tabularnewline
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

I only used `[p]` as placemnet specifier for the example to make the table float to the second page.

Comment: Thanks @Gonzalo for your help again. Your provided code works fine in LaTeX but if I export this to LyX, still I've the same problem in LyX. Might some issue with LyX.

Answer (score 2):

Something strange happens on import to LyX. If you look at the source code generated by LyX, the start of the `tikzpicture` is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}{[}remember picture,overlay{]}
```

while it should be

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
```

Note that on import, `\begin{tikzpicture}` is in an ERT, while `[remember picture,overlay]` is not. Move the latter part into the ERT, and it works fine here.

Comment: Thanks Torbjorn for your answer. Now it is working perfectly. But I have to accept the answer of @Gonzalo because that is more elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for finding this bug, Torbjørn T. I reported it and it was fixed (by Georg Baum) in LyX for version 2.2.0. For more details, see http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/9011