# putting rectangle inside tabular environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

Someone can help me to do like this exemple :
 [image: rectangle in tabular]

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: Is [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163614/4821) of any help?

Comment: As it stands, you haven't really asked a question, and you've made a statement: 'Someone can help me with this example'. The statement is certainly true, but it'd be great to know which part is giving you difficulty. Please provide the community with some code to show what you have tried

Comment: \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline

\backslashbox{Études}{Sexe}&M&F&$\Sigma   $ \\  

\hline
litt&60 \; \color{red}{72}&60 \; \color{red}{48}&120 \\

\hline

Sc&42 \; \color{red}{36}&18 \; \color{red}{24}&60 \\

\hline
Tech&18 \; \color{red}{12}&2 \; \color{red}{8}&20 \\

\hline
$\Sigma  $ &120&80&$ n = 200$ \\

\hline



\end{tabular}